# If $f'(x)= \frac{f(x)}{x}-e^{\frac{f(x)}{x}}$, prove that $f(x)=-x\ln(\ln(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let f be an differentiable function,  $f:(1, \infty)\rightarrow R$ , $f(e)=0$ and $$f'(x)= \frac{f(x)}{x}-e^{\frac{f(x)}{x}} \quad \forall x >1.$$ I am asked to prove that $f(x)=-x\ln(\ln(x))$. I thought of two ways, maybe one would be to maybe set as $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}-e^{\frac{f(x)}{x}}$ ,or $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ but I don't know how to continue with that.
I also tried:
We will prove that $$f(x)=-x\ln(\ln(x)) \Rightarrow -\frac{f(x)}{x}=\ln(\ln(x)) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{e^{\frac{f(x)}{x}}}=\ln(x)$$ and try to prove that f is the one, by using the constant function theorem but again I seem to reach a dead-end. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 2):

let $\dfrac{y}{x}=t\space\space\space(y=f(x))
$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=t+x\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$
$$t+x\dfrac{dt}{dx}=t-e^{t}$$
$$\dfrac{dx}{x}=-\dfrac{dt}{e^t}$$
$$\int \dfrac{dx}{x}=-\int \dfrac{dt}{e^t}$$
$$\ln(x)=e^{-t}+c$$
Now as we know, $f(e)=0$, therefore plugging the value $x=e $ in the expression above, $c=0$

$$e^{-\big(\frac{y}{x}\big)}=\ln(x)$$

Therefore $y=f(x)=-x(\ln(\ln(x))$

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance, because I'll be denoting $ \left(u\left(x\right)\right)' $ to designate the derivative of $ x\mapsto u\left(x\right) \cdot $

We have, forall $ x\in\left]1,+\infty\right[ : $

\begin{aligned} \iff\ \ \ \ \  f'\left(x\right)-\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}&=-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\right)'&=-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}\\ \iff \left(-\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\right)'\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}&=\frac{1}{x}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}\right)'&=\frac{1}{x}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}&=\ln{x}\\ \iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  f\left(x\right)&=-x\ln{\left(\ln{x}\right)} \end{aligned}

Comment: Shouldn't you add a constant, which you can fix with the "initial condition", in the next to the last line?

Comment: Yes, to get from the fourth line to the fifth one, I surely did use the initial condition given, so as not to break the equivalence.